# Matplotlib, python. How are create new plot on old figure window.

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a function that let user to click on a data point on a graph. Then on_pick function will generate a new figure. The problem I have now is that each time I click on a data a new figure window is created. Is there a way to reuse the same figure window and create a new plot on that window?
I tried to put figure(2) before plotpot function (the function that generates the plot) hoping to tell python to always use that window. But instead it generated an empty figure(2) and put my plot in figure(3) and so on.

Thanks for you advice.

Jiajun

```
def plotpot(data2d, sigma=.1, Nx=40, Ny=40):
    # ensure the data sending for plotpot is always in 2d. 
    potmap = zeros((Nx, Ny))
    for i in range(Nx):
        for j in range(Ny):
            x = float(i)/Nx-0.5
            y = float(j)/Ny-0.5
            potmap[j,i] = potential_ds(data2d, np.array([x,y]), sigma)

    matshow(potmap, cmap=cm.gray, extent=(-0.5,0.5,0.5,-0.5))
    plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], ".")
    axis([-0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5])

def on_pick(event):

    global data, vel, sigma
    vel = rand(dim); vel /= norm(vel)/1
    artist = event.artist
    ind = event.ind
    indNp = np.array(ind)

    pos = np.array(data[indNp[0],:])
    # a Function to calculate trajectory
    trj = PTSM(pos, data, vel, sigma = sigma, dt = dt, r = .9995, Nsamp = 15000)

    # create a potential plot
    plotpot(data[:, 0:2], sigma)
    plot(trj[:,1], trj[:,2], "-", lw=0.7, c = "green")
```